# Regex to strip characters except given ones?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, c#-4.0

I would like to strip strings but only leave the following:

```
[a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*
```

I am trying to output strings that start with a character, then can have alphanumeric, underscores, and dashes. How can I do this with RegEx or another function?

Comment: you've got the regex - what is it exactly that you are having problems with ?

Comment: By strings to you mean a `string[]`? Isn't "getting all the matches" the same as "not getting things that don't match"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because everything in the second part of the regex is in the first part, you could do something like this:

```
String foo = "_-abc.!@#$5o993idl;)"; // your string here.
//First replace removes all the characters you don't want.
foo = Regex.Replace(foo, "[^_a-zA-Z0-9-]", "");
//Second replace removes any characters from the start that aren't allowed there.
foo = Regex.Replace(foo, "^[^a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

So start out by paring it down to only the allowed characters. Then get rid of any allowed characters that can't be at the beginning.

Of course, if your regex gets more complicated, this solution falls apart fairly quickly.

Answer (score 0):

> Edited

```
   var s = Regex.Matches(input_string, "[a-z]+(_*-*[a-z0-9]*)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            string output_string="";
            foreach (Match m in s)
            {
                output_string = output_string + m;

            }
    MessageBox.Show(output_string);
```

Comment: That's weird.. inputting this sdgfsd*^%&$AFSds returns sdgfsd. It's like it quits after finding a special string.

Comment: @TruMan1 What do you mean by strip? OP is asking about stripping string from given string.

Comment: I would expect sdgfsd*^%&$AFSds to return sdgfsdAFSds but it is returning sdgfsd.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've got the strings in a collection, I would do it this way:

1. foreach element in the collection try match the regex
2. if !success, remove the string from the collection

Or the other way round - if it matches, add it to a new collection.

If the strings are not in a collection can you add more details as to what your input looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull out all of the identifiers matching your regular expression, you can do it like this:

```
var input = " _wontmatch f_oobar0 another_valid ";
var re = new Regex( @"\b[a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\b" );
foreach( Match match in re.Matches( input ) )
    Console.WriteLine( match.Value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MatchCollection matchColl = Regex.Matches("input string","your regex");`

Then use:

```
string [] outStrings = new string[matchColl.Count]; //A string array to contain all required strings

for (int i=0; i < matchColl.Count; i++ )
     outStrings[i] = matchColl[i].ToString();
```

You will have all the required strings in outStrings. Hope this helps.